# mayday: CSS fonts look horrible different in IE compared to Chrome/Firefox after update

Tags: html, xhtml, css

My site used to look the same in IE, Chrome, Firefox.  Today, I looked at the online site (http://www.skytop.at/) and the fonts are a complete mess in IE8, but fine in Chrome and Firefox.

I desperately need a quick fix, since the client will be very pissed ;-(

Please look at the site in IE (e.g. IE8) versus Chrome/Firefox:

http://www.skytop.at/index.html
http://skytop.at/gastronomie.html
http://skytop.at/terrasse.html

or the other subpages.

any fix is welcome.

Thanks a lot,
Steve

Comment: Looks fine for me in both FF/Chrome and IE 8. I think you will need to post screen shots.

Comment: Yeah, looks alright for me as well.

Comment: The fonts look identical in IE8 and Firefox 4.0 beta 1.

Comment: NB: the site is very broken in IE6.

Comment: Try something like Browsershots to find out how it actually looks on different browsers on different OS'es.

Comment: =====

SOLVED!! it really was just resetting to IE8 defaults.

100000 time thanks.

I totaly thought it was my mistake and panicked ;-)


skytop.at/screenshot1.png
skytop.at/screenshot2.png

nothing similar happend the last 5 years.

Comment: @user391399: then it was almost certainly your ClearType setting that was disabled, if resetting IE8 to defaults worked.  That's the only setting that could affect the quality of font rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, it looks fine for them in Internet Explorer.  This means you probably have ClearType disabled in your Internet Explorer settings.

[image]
<sub>(source: [winisp.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20110412103908/http://ieblog.members.winisp.net/images/VerdanaCompareVertical.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [winisp.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20110412103913/http://ieblog.members.winisp.net/images/ct-inetcpl.jpg))</sub>

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905191705/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ie/archive/2006/02/03/524367.aspx)